# AVAssetImageGenerator generating images with green pixels using animation tool and video composition

Tags: ios, swift, avassetimagegenerator

I am generating animated gif from a mutable composition where I am setting `AVMutableVideoComposition` with `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`. Problem is with core animation tool, when it's set generated images have 1 column of green pixels on the very right. If I don't add core animation tool it works perfectly.

Example of generated gif is here:

[image]

This is how I am creating `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` object with layers.

```
let parentLayer = CALayer()
let videoLayer = CALayer()
let assetsLayer = self.assetsLayer!
assetsLayer.isGeometryFlipped = true
parentLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: videoComposition.renderSize)
videoLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: videoComposition.renderSize)
assetsLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: videoComposition.renderSize)
parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
parentLayer.addSublayer(assetsLayer)
videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)
```

I found out that if I make video layer 2 pixels wider so that green pixels are offscreen it will work. But it's dirty hack.

```
videoLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: videoComposition.renderSize).insetBy(dx: -2, dy: -2)
```

Does anyone know why I am having green column and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Peter. I'm using AVVideoComposition as well. For some reason some of my frames aren't rendered at all, giving me empty NULL CGImage. Do you have any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I was specifying render size of `AVMutableVideoComposition` with odd value of width (375px). It looks like I have to use even numbers only because rendered video was 376px wide and renderer probably let me know that it added 1 extra column. Strange that this is not mentioned in wwdc videos nor programming guide.